# Metric such that the diameter of a set is always less than or equal to 1

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Given a metric d, we wish to modify it so that the diameter of any set will be bounded by above from 1. How can one find such a metric which works for every set?

Answer (score 2):

Let $d'(x,y) = \min\{d(x,y),1/2\}$.

Comment: Would the following also work? If X has finite diameter, say D, then let $d'(x,y)=d(x,y)/D$. If X is infinite then define $d(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Defining $d(x,y) = 0$ doesn't define a metric. In the case $D < \infty$ your definition of $D'$ works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method:
$d'(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$. This has the advantage that one can reconstruct the original metric by the formula $d(x,y)=\frac{d'(x,y)}{1-d'(x,y)}$. (Note that $d'(x,y)<1$ for any $x$ and $y$.)

Comment: Does this metric also preserve openness and closeness of sets? My intuition tells me no, since d' seems to "even out" the distance between points.

Comment: Yes it does, because any open ball $\{x:d(x,x_0)<\varepsilon\}$ in the original metric is the open ball $\{x:d'(x,x_0)<\varepsilon'\}$, where $\varepsilon'=\varepsilon/(1+\varepsilon)$, in the new metric.